# How to decide between sizes of particles for maximum light intensity for scintillation?

Tags: radiation, nuclear-engineering, nanoscience, optical-materials

Are nanoparticles or microparticles or quantum dots better suited as scintillation materials as far as light yield intensity is concerned? I was unable to find literature that compares micro vs nanoparticles for light intensity on fluorescing. For example, I'm looking to use ZnS-Ag, but cannot decide between micro and nano particles (I currently have 10 micron long particles, but not sure if its optimum as I also cannot find nano particles of the same material)